# solve the inequations and provide the solutions in brackets

Tags: calculus

I have 2 inequations which I solve, but when I compare the result with websites like wolframalpha I get different results.

$|2-x|+|2+x| \leq 10$

I continue with $2-x+2-x\leq10$ OR $2-x+2-x\geq-10$ 
and I get the results $x\geq3$ and $x\leq7 $

$|6-4x|\geq|x-2|$
$6-4x \geq x-2$ OR $6-4x \leq -x+2 $
and I get $x\leq8/5$ and $x\geq4/3$

Are my results correct or not?

Thank you

Comment: to solve the inequations?

Answer (score 1):

You have two critical points (points that evaluate to zero in the absolute values). These are $x=2$ and $x=-2$. Now you have three cases which you have to look at $x\in(-\infty,-2]$, $x\in (-2,2]$ and $x\in (2,\infty)$ [Note: these intervals are important because the expressions in the absolute value functions change sign].

For your second problem the critical points are. $6-4x=0 \to x=\frac{6}{4}$ and $x-2=0 \to x = 2$. What cases do we have to check now?

EDIT: Steps for solving such equations:

1. write down all terms with absolute values: Here $|2-x|$ and $|2+x|$.
2. find value of x for which these absolute values evaluate to $0$: Here $x=2$ and $x=-2$. These values are called the critical values
3. Split the real axis at the critical values ($-2, 2$): Here (a) $x\in(-\infty,-2]$, (b) $x\in (-2,2]$ and (c)$x\in (2,\infty)$
4. Look at all cases (a), (b) and (c) separately: Here

(a): First absolute value is positive and the second is negative: $(2-x)-(2+x) \leq 10$. Solving this $-2x \leq 10$ or $x\geq -5$. Compare with (a) $x\in(-\infty,-2]$ to conclude that only values for $x \in [-5,-2]$ are valid solutions for case (a).

(b): First absolute value is positive and the second is positive: $(2-x)+(2+x) \leq 10$. Solving this leads to $4\leq 10$, which is valid for all $x$. Compare with (b) $x\in (-2,2]$ to conclude that only values for  $x\in (-2,2]$ are valid solutions for case (b).

(c): First absolute value is negative and the second is positive: $-(2-x)+(2+x)\leq10$ or $2x\leq 10$ or $x\leq5$. Compare with (c) $x\in (2,\infty)$ to conclude that only $x\in (2,5]$ are valid solutions.

Now combine alle the cases (a), (b) and (c) to conclude that all $x\in [-5,5]$ are solutions to the inequality
I leave the rest to you.

Comment: For the second problem, do I need to move all the absolute values in one side?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Shouldn't (a) be (-∞,-2) ?

Comment: inclusion of $x=-2$ to (a) or (b) is arbitrary. it results in a zero for the absolute value. The same is true for $x=2$. You can incude it in (b) or (c).

Comment: Last questions, are these critical values correct? (a) (-∞, -2) ; (b) ([-2,2]) ; (c) (2,+∞) ?

Comment: These are intervals:). Critical points are $x=\pm2$. As long as you include $x=\pm2$ in case (b) it is ok:).

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong because you don't manage correctly the sign of the expressions in the absolute values.

In your first inequality you have $ 2-x\ge 0 \iff x\le 2$ and $2+x \ge 0 \iff x\ge -2$. So the inequality  reduces to three systems:
$$
\begin{cases}
x<-2\\
2-x-2-x\le 10
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
-2\le x<2\\
2-x+2+x\le 10
\end{cases}
\lor
\begin{cases}
x\ge 2\\
x-2+2+x\le 10
\end{cases}
$$

look well at these systems and understand where they come from, than solve  and find the solution $-5\le x\le 5$ or, in brakets; $[-5,5]$.

Than use the same method for the other inequality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I don't understand how you created the systems. I don't understand the second line in each system, how you define if one expression in the absolute value turns to be positive or negative?

Comment: You know that for $x<-2$ the argument of the first absolute value is positive, so you can write $|2-x|=2-x$ and the argument of the second absolute value is negative, so we have $|2+x|=-2-x$.. and so one for the others cases...

Comment: Now I get it. You learned sth in 2 mins that my professor didn't explain at all. Thank you very much. Last question, about the second inequation, do I need to move the absolute values in the same side?

Comment: Anyway, I understood it. Thank you

Comment: it is not necessary to move the absolute values at the same side... but it can be useful. what is important is to divide the real line in the correct intervals, finding and ordering all the critical points. Note that the *crtical points* are the points where the arguments of the absolute values change sign.